# Away3d move camera in viewing direction?

Tags: actionscript-3, away3d

I have Away3D camera looking at an object from aerial view.

Now, I want to get closer to that object as I rotate mouse wheel.

I did it using camera lens but it is like adjusting binocular and not actually getting closer to that object,

```
private function onMouseWheelEvent(e:MouseEvent):void
{
      PerspectiveLens(view.camera.lens).fieldOfView -= e.delta;         
}
```

Is there any easy solution to this or I will have to write such controller of my own?

Comment: How do you normally move your camera? Just move it by view direction vector.

Comment: I have used moveUp(), moveDown() to move camera. I don't know how to calculate direction vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it using `camera.forwardVector` like so,

```
private function onMouseWheelEvent(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    view.camera.x = view.camera.x + (e.delta * view.camera.forwardVector.x);
    view.camera.y = view.camera.y + (e.delta * view.camera.forwardVector.y);
    view.camera.z = view.camera.z + (e.delta * view.camera.forwardVector.z);
}
```

Comment: Cool. It was just a matter of studying properties, but it's always good to do some research, right? :)